# Maximize weights in a weighted average using Lagrange multipliers

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, average

For values $\mathbf{a}=(a_1, a_2, ..., a_N)$ with corresponding weights $\mathbf{w}=(w_1, w_2, ..., w_N)$ (assume $\sum_{i=1}^{N} w_i = 1$ and $0 \le w_j \le 1$ for $j \in {\{1,2,...,N\}}$), the weighted average is

$$
\bar{a} = \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_i a_i
$$

How can I solve for the weights $\mathbf{w}$ that maximize $\bar{a}$ using the method of Lagrange multipliers?

It is obvious that the solution will give a value 1 to the weight that corresponds to the largest value in $\mathbf{a}$, and 0 for the remaining weights, e.g. $\mathbf{a}=(1,2,3)$ will give $\mathbf{w}=(0,0,1)$ and $\bar{a}=3$. However, I am somehow not able to show this using Lagrange Multipliers.

What I have tried is to solve the following set of equations ($j \in {\{1,2,...,N\}}$)
$$
\dfrac{\partial \bar{a}}{\partial w_j} = \lambda \dfrac{\partial g}{\partial w_j}
$$
with the constraint equation

$$
g = \sum_{i=1}^{N} w_i = 1
$$

I then calculate $\dfrac{\partial \bar{a}}{\partial w_j} = a_j$ and $\dfrac{\partial g}{\partial w_j} = 1$, and thus get $a_j = \lambda$ for all $j$ which is obviously not always true, and moreover the equations are independent of $w_j$'s to solve for.

It seems like a straightforward problem. How is this done correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Both the function You want to optimize and the constraint are $N$ dimensional plane and their normal vectors do not necessarily coincide. This lead to one of the followings:

1. $a_{i}$ are all equal, mean any weights combination yields the same weighted average which is $a_{i}$ itself or
2. $a_{i}$ are not all equal, means the extrema is located on the ends of “interval” i.e. one weight equals to $1$ while the others equal to $0$. Maxima if the weight of the biggest $a_{i}$ is $1$ and minima if the weight of the smallest $a_{i}$ is $1$

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the Lagrangian method while ignoring $0 \le w_j \le 1$ constraints. In fact, for optimization problems with inequality constraints, you need to use the  generalized version of the Lagrangian method known as [KKT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker_conditions) conditions.  However, if you want to use the classical Lagrangian method, you need to somehow modify your optimization problem such that it does not have an inequality constraint. For instance, letting $w_i =   v_{i}^{2}$, you can solve the following optimization problem:

minimize $\sum_{i=1}^{n} v_{i}^{2} a_i$ subject to $\sum_{i=1}^{n} v_{i}^{2} =1.$ After finding all $v_i$s in the previous problem, you can retrieve all the $w_i$s using the relationship between $v_i$ and $w_i$.

P.S. I leave it to you to convince yourself why these two optimization problems are equivalent.